# retrofit2.4 + adapter-rxjava2 + proguard

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2, android-proguard

[image: Screenshot]

error is as follow:

```
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by:   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for class  io.reactivex.Flowable
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime:     for method RequestApis.getCameraInfo
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime:    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError()
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime:    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter()
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime:    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build()
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime:    at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod()
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime:    at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke()
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime:    at $Proxy0.getCameraInfo(Unknown Source)
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.youlecamera.upload.helper.RetrofitHelper.getCameraInfo()
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.youlecamera.awsIot.IotService.bind()
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.youlecamera.awsIot.IotService.aZ()
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.youlecamera.awsIot.IotService$1.onReceive()
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:922)
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 7 more
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Flowable return type must be parameterized as  Flowable<Foo> or Flowable<? extends Foo>
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime:    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.get()
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime:    at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter()
03-11 14:28:14.401 11858 11858 E AndroidRuntime:    at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter()
```

my proguard is:

[image: Proguard]

I tried modifying proguard many times, but it did not work,
how can I do? Who can help me? thanks

my code as below,please help to check,thanks.

```
{
         ...
        OkHttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();
        Log.w(TAG, "RequestRetrofit", new Throwable());
        ...
        String url = (version == Constants.VERSION_PRE) ? RequestApis.HOST : RequestApis._HOST;
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .client(client)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        service = retrofit.create(RequestApis.class);
    }
```

Comment: always post code as **text**, not as images

Comment: [edit] your question, don't post code in comments

Comment: is it working without proguard?

Comment: This happens usually when you forgot to add the rxjava call adapter to Retrofit. Can you post the code for how you're initializing the Retrofit instance please?

Comment: @Basi, it work well without proguard.

Comment: @Fred, i have added code,pls check it.

Comment: add `-keep class retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory { *; }` to progaurd

Comment: check this [link](https://gist.github.com/jemshit/767ab25a9670eb0083bafa65f8d786bb)

Comment: @Basi, i modify it as you said, but still not work, same error.

Comment: @Basi, i have checked your link, and modified it ,but still not work.  crying

Comment: I used adapter-rxjava2-2.4.0.jar and retrofit-2.4.0.jar

Comment: Ah taking a deeper look into the exception, seems like in your API you specified it as returnning `Flowable` instead of parameterizing it with the class you want, i.e., `Flowable<Foo>`. Is this true?

Comment: @POST("management/camera_base_info")

    Flowable<HttpResponse<BindInfoBean>> getCameraInfo();

    from code, it should return Flowable<>

Comment: what'more, i used rxjava:libs/rxjava-2.1.14.jar

Comment: how to proguard io.reactivex?

 -dontwarn io.reactivex.**

 -keep class io.reactivex.** { *; }